# Retrieving elements from array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays in js

```
var array1=new Array("KS","NB","SD","ND","MN");
var array2=new Array("TX","LA","OK","AR");
```

Some how I will get the name of the array that should be retrieved.
Now what I want is, if I get

```
var arrayTobeSelected = 'array1';
```

If I console.log arrayTobeSelected, what I get is the string 'array1'.
How can I get the elements in the array array1 ?

Comment: just console.log(arrar1);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If arrays are  in the global scope, you can do:

```
console.log(window[arrayToBeSelected]);// you can do [0] or [1] to get specific elements
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a string because:

```
var arrayTobeSelected = 'array1';
```

and not:

```
var arrayTobeSelected = array1;
```

if you have to get it as string, then just do this:

```
console.log(eval(arrayTobeSelected));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for print all the element of array.

```
 for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
             console.log(i + " = " + array[i]);
   }
       console.log(array);
       console.log("end");
```